# Smd resistor code= IEE

Tags: pcb, resistors, surface-mount, code

[image]

r28=iee what is meaning of iee code of smd resistor?

Comment: Any possibility that you are reading 331 upside-down?

Comment: Turn it other way up ... 331 = 330 ohms.

Comment: This reminds me of the time that I tried to figure out the purpose for the 710 cap in my car.

Answer (score 2):

That's 331 but upside-down. It means 33 and shifting the decimal point right by 1 number, i.e times ten. 330 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, 331 is 330 Ohms.

For 3 digit resistance codes, the way I remember it is that you replace the last digit with that number of zeros. For example, "330" is "33" with "0" zeros at the end. 33 Ohms.

And "331" is "33" with 1 zero: 330 Ohms.

"472" is "47" followed by "00" which is 4700 or 4.7k.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Some manufacturers do *not* follow the standard convention unfortunately (digit 1, digit 2, possibly digit 3, multiplier) I have seen a 330 mean 330 ohms (not the 33 it would be according to the convention).

Comment: I didn't mean to say that this is the only system.